# Two-finger swipe gesture on GridView for UWP touch app

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I am trying to implement a two-finger swipe gesture for multi-selection of `GridView`. But I can't receive required pointer events for counting the number of fingers which are touching the screen. I am testing with Dell P2314T during development.

The order of pointer event fireing:
Theoretical:`PointerPressed`(pressed)=>`PointerMoved`(swiping)=>`PointerReleased` (released)
Actual:`PointerPressed` & `PointerCaptureLost` (when pressed but not released)

PS: The demo is removed.

Here is a snippet of my code, which obviously doesn't work because `PointerMoved` and `PointerReleased` don't fire:

```
class CustomGridView : GridView
{
    List<uint> pointerPoint = new List<uint>();
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        (element as GridViewItem).AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(OnPointerPressed), true);
        (element as GridViewItem).PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;
        (element as GridViewItem).PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
    private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pointerPoint.Contains(e.Pointer.PointerId))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("add:" + e.Pointer.PointerId);
            pointerPoint.Add(e.Pointer.PointerId);
        }
    }
    private void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pointerPoint.Count == 2)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("two finger");
        }
    }
    private void OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pointerPoint.Contains(e.Pointer.PointerId))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("rem:" + e.Pointer.PointerId);
            pointerPoint.Remove(e.Pointer.PointerId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried above code, and it works well, could share what device you have tested with ?

Comment: I am testing with Dell P2314T touch monitor. I am testing on a GridView with minimal customization after posting, which gives the same result.

Comment: I run your code with Grid and it works. Could you share a demo project for us?

Comment: The demo project is attached. You can see one GridView and one image, both attached with same events. While events fire properly when tapping the image, but not the GridView.

Comment: Great, I will check your code project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:
Base on observation, `ScrollViewer` will capture the remaining pointer events.
`ScrollViewer` should be disabled and ongoing direct manipulation should be canceled when `PointerPressed` is fired.

XAML:

```xml
<GridView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="{x:Bind GridViewScrollMode}"/>
```

C#:

```cs
private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pointerPoints.Add(e.Pointer.PointerId);
    if (PointerIds.Count == 2)
    {
        ((sender as GridView).ContainerFromIndex(0) as GridViewItem).CancelDirectManipulations();
        GridViewScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
    }
}
```